# Is gradle and cordova 'couple' stable

Tags: cordova, gradle

I read a lot about gradle, and it seems to be a better solution than maven or ant.

But does it work well with cordova?

I'm using android studio, and wondering if gradle is mature enough to work with cordova based project.

I don't see a lot of info about this *couple*, and I'm afraid not to find a lot of answer if I had some issues with gradle in my cordova project.

Comment: Cordova project seems to have some code to setup Android Studio /Gradle projects https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3445 - but I haven't figured out how to access them...